# why nsstring is gone when used in another class?

Tags: objective-c

in classA i have :

```
classB *classBI=[[classB alloc]init];
bits=[classBI data]; //bits has a property here in classA,it gets data from B/
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(38.f, 20.f, 244.f, 43.f)];
label.text = bits;
```

in classB i have :

```
    @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *data; //in .h file
    data=@"no data"; //at the init method of classB .

    //then after a while when something is happen in classB , data is changed to :
    data=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f",
         dataBits[0],dataBits[1],dataBits[2],dataBits[3],dataBits[4],dataBits[5]  ];
```

classA is the main scene (cocos2d but it does not matter). at the start i can really see in the label that in classA the word "no data", but when data is changed in classB, i cant see that change in the label that is on screen. it stay with the word: "no data "
why is that ?
why i lost data ?
if i NSLOG data in classB ,right after it changed in there,i can see that its not null,and it has the new value. something is wrong with the instance of B ,in A, that get this string.

Comment: You have to update the label somewhere! Setting it once won't automagically "bind" it to class b's value. Where do you update the label?

Comment: i dont.. but its a pointer- is it not getting the values "always" ?

Comment: No, it is pointing at the **string** which says "no data".  When you set data to a new string, bits is still pointing to the old one.

Comment: @ lnafziger wow, but whats the point of pointers ? if i point you , so from now on where ever you look, i see what you see-or what you point at.. if you change that, i will also changed no ? or thats not the way with labels specifically ?

Comment: You are pointing to a specific object (a `NSString` in this case).  In this way, you can have multiple references to the same object.  However, **any** of the pointers can be changed to another object and it does not automatically updated all of the other pointers.  This is what you are doing.  Now if you use a `NSMutableString` and have pointers to it, *as long as you don't replace the entire object* you can **modify** the contents of the mutable string and it will be reflected when you inspect it using another pointer.  That is because it is the same object though.

Comment: Note that label.text is a `NSString` though so you can not make changes to it (since it isn't mutable) and your only option is to replace it.  It's hard to go into the fine points of how this works in a comment, so I would suggest that you search SO (and Google) for more info on how pointers work, and if you are still confused then ask a specific question on here for more info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the label's text to the string pointed to by `bits`, it is storing a reference to **that string**.  Later when you change `data`, it is creating a new string which `data` is pointing to, but `bits` and the label both still have the original pointer which is looking at the original string.  You want to update them whenever `data` is changed:

There are several approaches to take in this situation, but one of the easiest would be to observe the `data` property of `classBI` for changes, and update both `bits` and the label whenever it changes:

```
[classBI addObserver:self 
          forKeyPath:@"data" 
             options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
             context:NULL];
```

Then, whenever data changes, this method will be called:

```
// Note that you will need to get a reference to 'label' in order for this to work:
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary*)change context:(void*)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"data"]) {
        bits = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
        label.text = bits;
    }
}
```

Comment: great answer thanks a lot ! but i dont understand that, if bits is pointing to data,so where ever data will point from now on, bits will also point, this is the thing with pointer no ?

Comment: i do get notification ,and bits has the new value . but label is still not change...

Comment: You need to create another property (similar to `bits` but a `UILabel`) for your label so that you can create it like you did before (but use self.label instead of a local variable) and then use it from observeValueForKeyPath and set the text like I did in the `label.text = bits;` line.